# Linq to Entities, match where value contains one or more strings

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, filtering

I have a data set I need to filter on a string value. If a property contains a specific string, the item is selected. That works fine

I need to change this to allow for a LIST of strings to test against

I could iterate objects and loop through selected values, storing matches in seperate list, but feel that there should be a better way.

Hope someone has a good example on how to acomplish this

```
//Gets a set of addresses, objects have several properties, one of them beeing (example):
                // o.ZipCity ="1000 Copenhagen"
                List<AddresObjectType> result = getAllAddresses();

                // Example : 1000,2000
                var listOfZip = context.Request["zip"].Split(Convert.ToChar(","));

                //Current code, just one value
                result = result.Where(t => t.ZipCity.Contains(context.Request["zip"])).ToList();

                //Code I need... 
                //IF any of the passed values are matched then include
                result = result.Where(t => t.ZipCity.Contains(listOfZip)).ToList();
```

SO desiered effect :
- Requested values "1000,2000,3000" (one to many values)
- Result set includes all that has a ZipCity value that contains at least one of the values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this one:

```
result = result.Where(t => listofZip.Contains(t.ZipCity)).ToList();
```

The `listOfZip` will contain the values of 1000, 2000, 3000 and you try to get all the cities whose zip is one of them.

**Update**

```
result = result.Where(t => listofZip.Any(zip=>t.ZipCity.Contains(zip)).ToList();
```

The `Any` extension method return true if there is any element in the listofZip that satisfies the predicate:

```
zip=>t.ZipCity.Contains(zip)
```

or false if there isn't any.

What does the predicate checks?

It checks if the current zip, is contained in the ZipCity. If so returns true. Otherwise, it returns false.

Comment: But.... the t.ZipCity is a string with for example "1000 Copenhagen". Parameters just has the zip-code, not the complete string - so the value should just contain "1000"

Comment: Spot on. I knew there was a short and precise way to do it. Thanks.